# Two colorbars on two subplots, same figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, colorbar

I am trying to make a matplotlib plot with two subplots, and one colorbar to the right of each subplot. Here is my code currently:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

X = tsne_out[:,0]
Y = tsne_out[:,1]
Z = tsne_out[:,2]

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (20,15))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax1.scatter(X, Y, c = material, s = df['Diameter (nm)']/4, cmap = plt.get_cmap('nipy_spectral', 11))
ax1.set_title("2D Representation", fontsize = 18)
ax1.set_xlabel("TSNE1", fontsize = 14)
ax1.set_ylabel("TSNE2", fontsize = 14)
ax1.set_xlim(-20,20)
ax1.set_ylim(-20,20)
ax1.set_xticks(list(range(-20,21,10)))
ax1.set_yticks(list(range(-20,21,10)))


cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=list(range(0,9)))
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=15) 
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(custom_ticks)  # horizontal colorbar


ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222, projection='3d')
ax2.scatter(X, Y, Z, c = material, s = df['Diameter (nm)']/4, cmap = plt.get_cmap('nipy_spectral', 11))
ax2.set_title("3D Representation", fontsize = 18)
ax2.set_xlabel("TSNE1", fontsize = 14)
ax2.set_ylabel("TSNE2", fontsize = 14)
ax2.set_zlabel("TSNE3", fontsize = 14)
ax2.set_xlim(-20,20)
ax2.set_ylim(-20,20)
ax2.set_zlim(-20,20)
ax2.set_xticks(list(range(-20,21,10)))
ax2.set_yticks(list(range(-20,21,10)))
ax2.set_zticks(list(range(-20,21,10)))

cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, ticks = list(range(0,9)))
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=15) 
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(custom_ticks)
```

This provides the following figure:
[image: Matplotlib produced figure]

My question is: why does the first colorbar not show my custom ticks and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be that [`ScalarMappable`](https://matplotlib.org/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable.colorbar) objects seem to be able to have at most one colorbar associated with them. When you draw the second colorbar with the same `ScalarMappable`, the original colorbar is unlinked and the previous settings are lost for the first colorbar.

Your code is missing some details (in particular, the definition of `cax`), so you either have to create two separate mappables, or directly use what each `scatter` call gives you. Furthermore, I'd be explicit about where you want to get your colorbars to be inserted.

An example fix, assuming that `cax` was really meant to refer to your scatter plots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

X = np.random.rand(100) * 40 - 20
Y = np.random.rand(100) * 40 - 20
Z = np.random.rand(100) * 40 - 20
C = np.random.randint(1,8,100)
custom_ticks = list('ABCDEFGH')

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (20,15))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
sc1 = ax1.scatter(X, Y, c = C, cmap='viridis') # use this mappable
ax1.set_title("2D Representation", fontsize = 18)
ax1.set_xlabel("TSNE1", fontsize = 14)
ax1.set_ylabel("TSNE2", fontsize = 14)
ax1.set_xlim(-20,20)
ax1.set_ylim(-20,20)
ax1.set_xticks(list(range(-20,21,10)))
ax1.set_yticks(list(range(-20,21,10)))


cbar = fig.colorbar(sc1, ax=ax1, ticks=list(range(0,9))) # be explicit about ax1
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=15) 
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(custom_ticks)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')
sc2 = ax2.scatter(X, Y, Z, c=C, cmap='viridis') # next time use this one
ax2.set_title("3D Representation", fontsize = 18)
ax2.set_xlabel("TSNE1", fontsize = 14)
ax2.set_ylabel("TSNE2", fontsize = 14)
ax2.set_zlabel("TSNE3", fontsize = 14)
ax2.set_xlim(-20,20)
ax2.set_ylim(-20,20)
ax2.set_zlim(-20,20)
ax2.set_xticks(list(range(-20,21,10)))
ax2.set_yticks(list(range(-20,21,10)))
ax2.set_zticks(list(range(-20,21,10)))

cbar = fig.colorbar(sc2, ax=ax2, ticks=list(range(0,9))) # sc1 here is the bug
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=15) 
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(custom_ticks)

plt.show()
```

This produces the following:

[image: created figure, fixed colorbar]

Note that I created an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for you, and I simplified a few things, for instance the number of subplots. The point is that the colorbar settings stick now that they use separate mappables.

---

Another option is to create your colorbars first (using the same `ScalarMappable` if you want to), then customize both afterwards:

```
sc = ax1.scatter(X, Y, c = C, cmap='viridis')
cbar1 = fig.colorbar(sc, ax=ax1, ticks=np.arange(0,9))
ax2.scatter(X, Y, Z, c=C, cmap='viridis')
cbar2 = fig.colorbar(sc, ax=ax2, ticks=np.arange(0,9)) # sc here too

for cbar in cbar1,cbar2:
    cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=15) 
    cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(custom_ticks)
```

The fact that the above works may suggest that the original behaviour is a bug.